# php timezone and timestamp

Tags: php

```
echo(time()); 
echo"<br>";
echo date("m/d/Y h:i", time());
```

with the above code I get

```
1477355817 //this convert into 10/25/2016 @ 12:36am (UTC)
10/24/2016 05:36
```

you can convert the time use the following link to see the issue.
http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

the number above is GMT time. which is 19 hours ahead? but the time below is correct to my timezone, how come?. This is creating issue with my session because php timestamp gives out `Greenwich Mean Time` resulting my session expires on creation.

Comment: Most likely your server and unixtimestamp.com are using different default timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: OP here, updated to codeingiter 3.1.1 somehow fixed it. CI release 3.1.1 update on a saturday and this issue happened on the monday. but there should not be any correlation between the two.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to set the timezone, use this.

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

or

`date_default_timezone_set('COUNTRY/CITY');`